# Windows 11 can't install pygame?

Tags: python, installation, pip, pygame, python-3.10

Yes, just as I said, my new laptop doesn't want to download pygame for me. It's running Windows 11, maybe it has something to do with it (?)

Anyways, here is what my lovely machine responded to a simple "`pip install pygame`":

```
C:\Users\User>pip install pygame
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.1.2-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (8.4 MB)
     ------ --------------------------------- 1.4/8.4 MB 23.1 kB/s eta 0:05:03
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 90, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\http\client.py", line 465, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1273, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ssl.py", line 1129, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 167, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 339, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 481, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 348, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 215, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 288, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 158, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 227, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 299, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 487, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 532, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 214, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 94, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 146, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 304, in _rich_progress_bar
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 512, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, As the last line says `timeout` you need to change the default time to something else.

```py
pip --default-timeout=1200 install pygame
```

Answer (score 0):

If your having trouble installing pygame on windows 11 use:

```
pip install pygame --pre
```